# how to hide calendar view in dynamic date picker on edit text on click

Tags: android

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }

};

edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new DatePickerDialog(new_split.this, date, myCalendar
            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
});

private void updateLabel() {

String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

edittext.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> >  got this worked by defining the datepicker dialog as a different
> > class by inheriting it and by defining interface....
> ```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DatePickerFragment.TheListener{
edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
});






public class DatePickerFragmenta extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
  TheListenera listenera;

  public interface TheListenera{
      public void returnaDate(String date);


  }

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      listenera = (TheListenera) getActivity(); 

      DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
      dialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
      dialog.setTitle("Pick a date");
      return dialog; 
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to tell what you're asking exactly, but in case you want to hide the `CalendarView` in `DatePickerDialog`, the following will work:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
}
```

(On API levels under 11 where `getDatePicker()` and `setCalendarViewShown()` are not available it does not matter - there's no `CalendarView` in the dialog anyway.)

Comment: this is not working frnd ...i tried by reducing target version too...error showing in DatePickerDialog...i tried this in oncreate() and mainactivity() also and also in onclick() too.....this simple thing is worrying a bit...please help me in this...

Comment: Please clarify the question by editing it.

Comment: i need to hide calendar view in date picker dialog..my API level 17..but the above code u given is not working ..code which i posted is the exact one under mainActivity and onCreate method

Comment: this is my exact code frnd in between mainActivity and onCreate method ..i dono to edit the code with this rules...i dono whr to include the above code u suggested...sorry if this is also not clear..